# How to change background color of a table cell in java script using row and column number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the background color of a cell depending on my `row` and `col` id. I have tried like this but didn't work.

```js
let rowNumber = 1;
let colNumber = 1;
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[rowNumber].cells.item(colNumber).style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0-0</td>
      <td>0-1</td>
      <td>0-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1-0</td>
      <td>1-1</td>
      <td>1-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2-0</td>
      <td>2-1</td>
      <td>2-2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code works fine, as you can see in the snippet I created. Please check your console for errors

Comment: Why you have included jQuery but doesn't use him?

Comment: You may use the CSS pseudo-class nth-child as well. See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0njL6hbz/

Comment: It is not working for me, I don't know what is wrong. Here is the error from console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Comment: That means the `document.getElementById("myTable")` is not returning your `table`. Ensure you're running your JS code when the DOM has been loaded, either in a load event, or by placing it just before `</body>`

Comment: thanks it worked...the problem was the table id wasn't correct!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'd suggest deleting the question if that was the error as this isn't going to be a benefit to any future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with CSS like this:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

Comment: This is not doing the same thing as the OP requests